# "Other/Miscellaneous" Icon Metaphor

Tags: icons, metaphor

We're designing an interface for task managament app for tablet and mobile app and there are two main category with "Waiting Tasks" and "Other Tasks". I once used three dot (...) icon metaphor for "Other Tasks" but I want to try alternative metaphor for this icon.

So I want to know is there any alternative metaphor for "Other/Miscellaneous" icon different than three dot?

Answer (score 2):

Unless an icon is absolutely necessary, have you considered using the full text or an abbreviation of the actual word or words? It will reduce the ambiguity created by an unfamiliar graphic representing of your concept.

Comment: Yes, I thought it. But it doesn't correspond with project brief. I need to go with icon solution.